# How to make allowsDirectInteraction covers whole screen?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a game in SwiftUI for blind and visually impaired people.
I made a setup where you hear a sound every time you tap the screen.
It is intended that the entire screen can be used for the game.
However, if you tap the top or bottom of the screen, VoiceOver says "Direct touch area".

Is it possible that the entire screen is used and that VoiceOver does not speaks the notification at the top and bottom?
Is there something I'm overlooking in my code?

The code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPlaying = false

    @ViewBuilder var activeView: some View {
    
    if isPlaying == false {
    
        MenuView(isPlaying: $isPlaying)
    
    } else {
    
        GameView(isPlaying: $isPlaying)
        
    }
    
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        activeView
            .statusBar(hidden: (isPlaying ? true : false))
            .toolbar((isPlaying ? .hidden : .visible), for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbar((isPlaying ? .hidden : .visible), for: .bottomBar)

    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct MenuView: View {
    
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Form {
                    
                    Button(action: startGame) {
                        
                        Text("Start game")
                            .font(.headline)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Game")
                
            }
            
        }
        
}

    func startGame() {
        
        isPlaying = true
        
    }
    
}

struct MenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuView(isPlaying: .constant(false))
    }
}


import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct GameView: View {
    
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    
    @AccessibilityFocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
    
            ZStack {
                
                Rectangle()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .padding(0)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .accessibilityAddTraits(.allowsDirectInteraction)
                    .accessibilityFocused($isFocused)
                    .onAppear {
                        
                        isFocused = true

                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                    
                    print("Tapped")
                    
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003)
                    
                }

                VStack {
                            
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .accessibilityHidden(true)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
                
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .font(.title)
                    .accessibilityHidden(true)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
                        
                }
                    
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

    }
    
}

struct GameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameView(isPlaying: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Kristof